# No Established Sessions corresponding to Session Indexes

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

I am testing wso2stratos-is-1.5.2 in a stand alone mode. I unzip the product. I enter the bin directory and run ./wso2server.sh , i login as admin, I try to logout and I get the following error message in the log file

> Stratos Identity]ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor}
>   -  No Established Sessions corresponding to Session Indexes provided. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor}

I wonder if some one of greater knowledge could inform me why this happens out of the box?

Comment: if i add all files and subdirectories under a working deploying of stratos is 1.5.2 of repository/conf then I can get this to work properly. So, this tells me that one or more of those conf files is making the stand alone version work. I just need to pinpoint what they are.

Answer (score 0):

What i ended up doing to fix this problem is like I said in my comment.

I copied the repository/conf/advanced directory from the working full stratos install IS Server and pasted it into the stand-alone version of Stratos IS. And made sure the port number in authenticators.xml was pointing to the stand-alone port number.

Then I copied the following files from the working Stratos IS Server and pasted into the Stand-alone version, modifying the port numbers to be relevant to the stand-alone
1. sso-idp-config.xml
2. Identity.xml
3. Carbon.xml

Now I can logout properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the ACS URL in the relying party entry related to Stratos IS in the sso-idp-config.xml has the same hostname as in the hostname parameter in carbon.xml.

Thanks,
Thilina